# Create a new copy of a data structure based on pointers

Tags: c

I started with a programming assignment. I had to design a DFA based on graphs. Here is the data structure I used for it:

```
typedef struct n{
    struct n *next[255];           //pointer to the next state. Value is NULL if no transition for the input character( denoted by their ascii value)
    bool start_state;
    bool end_state;
}node;
```

Now I have a DFA graph-based structure ready with me. I need to utilize this DFA in several places; The DFA will get modified in each of these several places. But I want unmodified DFAs to be passed to these various functions. One way is to create a copy of this DFA. What is the most elegant way of doing this? So all of them are initialized either with a NULL value or some pointer to another state.

**NOTE:**
I want the copy to be created in the called function i.e. I pass the DFA, the called function creates its copy and does operation on it. This way, my original DFA remains undeterred.

**MORE NOTES:**
From each node of a DFA, I can have a directed edge connecting it with another edge, If the transition takes place when there the input alphabet is `c` then `state->next[c]` will have a pointer of the next node. It is possible that several elements of the `next` array are NULL. Modifying the NFA means both adding new nodes as well as altering the present nodes.

Comment: `memcpy()` the struct, then recursively `memcpy()` the items of `next`?

Comment: Will the modifications modify the pointers in the array `next`, or will they modify the `struct n` values that they point to?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes. The node value can be modifies(i.e. the final_state and start_state) as well as new node might be introduced in the next array.

Comment: You could add a "visited" field to node and have another higher level struct called "root" which has the pointer to the root node and a linked list of all the nodes in the graph.

Comment: There are several clarifications still needed before I understand it, and I suggest putting the answer(s) into the question.  You have an array `next` of 255 pointers; will all those be set to non-null values?  Or will it be just a few?  Which few?  Given: `node n;` and initialization, will all of `n->next[n->start_state]`..`n->next[n->end_state]` be initialized (and none of the others)? Or will all be initialized appropriately, but some will be null pointers; or will none of them be null pointers? You mention 'new nodes' which has me puzzled; would these replace an existing node, or be added?

Answer (score 2):

If you need a private copy on each call, and since this is a linked data structure, I see no way to avoid copying the whole graph (except perhaps to do a copy-on-write to some sub branches if the performance is that critical, but the complexity is significant and so is the chance of bugs).

Had this been c++, you could have done this in a copy constructor, but in c you just need to clone on every function. One way is to clone the entire structure (Like Mark suggested) - it's pretty complicated since you need to track cycles/ back edges in the graph (which manifest as pointers to previously visited nodes that you don't want to reallocate but reuse what you've already allocated).

Another way, if you're willing to change your data structure, is to work with arrays - keep all the nodes in a single array of type node. The array should be big enough to accommodate all nodes if you know the limit, or just reallocate it to increase upon demand, and each "pointer" is replaced by a simple index.

Building this array is different - instead of mallocing a new node, use the next available index (keep it on the side), or if you're going to add/remove nodes on the fly, you could keep a queue/stack of "free" indices (populate at the beginning with 1..N, and pop/push there whenever you need a new location or about to free an old one.

The upside is that copying would be much faster, since all the links are relative to the instance of the array, you just copy a chunk of contiguous memory (memcpy would now work fine)

Another upside is that the performance of using this data structure should be superior to the linked one, since the memory accesses are spatially close and easily prefetchable.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to write a recursive function that visits all the nodes, with a global dictionary that keeps track of the mapping from the source graph nodes to the copied graph nodes. This dictionary will be basically a table that maps old pointers to new pointers.

Here's the idea. I haven't compiled it or debugged it...

```
struct {
 node* existing;
 node* copy
} dictionary[MAX_NODES] = {0};

node* do_copy(node* existing) 
{
  node* copy;
  int i;
  for(i=0;dictionary[i].existing;i++) {
    if (dictionary[i].existing == existing) return dictionary[i].copy;
  }
  copy = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  dictionary[i].existing = existing;
  dictionary[i].copy = copy;

  for(int j=0;j<255 && existing->next[j];j++) {
      node* child = do_copy(existing->next[j]);
      copy->next[j] = child;
  }
  copy->end_state = existing->end_state;
  copy->start_start = existing->start_state;
  return copy;

 }
```